# Using @Prop decorator for TypeScript - compilers gives error asking to initialise prop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tslint

I am using Vue with TypeScript and `vue-property-decorator` package.

When I am using a prop like so:

```
@Prop({ default: '' }) private type: string
```

I get a TS compiler error: `Property 'type' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

But then if I initialise it with something like:

```
@Prop({ default: '' }) private type: string = ''
```

Then I get a warning in my browser console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:587 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten 
whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's 
value. Prop being mutated: "type"
```

So what should I do in this scenario to not have any errors or warnings?

The only thing I can think of is to set: `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in tsconfig.json, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50425984/3995261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial error message is a result of TypeScript's *Strict Class Initialization* (introduced in 2.7). The release notes for 2.7 describe using the [definite assignment operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) (`!`) to address this issue. In your case, you'd do this:

```
@Prop({ default: '' }) private type!: string
```