# Vue Prop has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am using props in Vue Class components. The props are defined in the constructor without a value. This compiles and  works fine, but since the latest VS Code / TSLint update, I get the following warning:

> Property 'tag' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Vue Class Component

```
export default class Browser extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: '', required:false})
  tag: string

  created(){
     console.log("the tag prop is " + this.tag)
  }
}
```

If I DO assign it, I get the Vue warning that you shouldn't manipulate a Prop in a child component.

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Since this seems primarily a linting problem, is there a way to disable this? Or is my code actually wrong?

Comment: Which version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: Gotta believe this is a linting issue, since you *do* provide a default in the decorator.

Comment: @BobHy Right but that value's provided at run-time not when tslint can see this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update 2020/06/15

My original answer I gave at the time was a intermittent solution and not the correct one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892296/8769328) answer is the correct way of doing this; Appending the prop name with a `!`.

#### Original Answer

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false,` to tsconfig.json's compilerOptions.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es2015",
            "dom",
            "ScriptHost"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 40):

You **don't** need set `strictPropertyInitialization": false` to solve this.

According to [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter#using-decorators-to-define-a-component) in Microsoft TypeScript-Vue-Starter repo:

> Properties are defined by prefixing instance variables with the
>   @Prop() decorator from the vue-property-decorator package. Because the
>   --strictPropertyInitialization option is on, we need to tell TypeScript that Vue will initialize our properties by appending a ! to
>   them. This tells TypeScript "hey, relax, someone else is going to
>   assign this property a value."

You just need to append the `!` to the prop name:

```
@Prop({default: '', required:false})
  tag!: string
```